# Qt5 missing opengl identifier's

Tags: opengl, compiler-errors, qt5

i try to compile simple Qt application and port it to Qt5 
in the pro file i included the opengl flag :

```
QT += opengl widgets
```

also the opengl Qt5 path is included :

```
..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\msvc2010\include\QtOpenGL
```

but when i compile the app im getting those compilation errors

```
1>qmpwidget.cpp(148): error C3861: 'glClearDepth': identifier not found
1>qmpwidget.cpp(159): error C3861: 'glLoadIdentity': identifier not found
1>qmpwidget.cpp(167): error C2065: 'GL_QUADS' : undeclared identifier
1>qmpwidget.cpp(167): error C3861: 'glBegin': identifier not found
1>qmpwidget.cpp(168): error C3861: 'glTexCoord2f': identifier not found
1>qmpwidget.cpp(168): error C3861: 'glVertex2f': identifier not found
1>qmpwidget.cpp(169): error C3861: 'glTexCoord2f': identifier not found
1>qmpwidget.cpp(169): error C3861: 'glVertex2f': identifier not found
1>qmpwidget.cpp(170): error C3861: 'glTexCoord2f': identifier not found
1>qmpwidget.cpp(170): error C3861: 'glVertex2f': identifier not found
1>qmpwidget.cpp(171): error C3861: 'glTexCoord2f': identifier not found
1>qmpwidget.cpp(171): error C3861: 'glVertex2f': identifier not found
1>qmpwidget.cpp(172): error C3861: 'glEnd': identifier not found
```

other opengl command do recognazied
what im missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append this word in .pro file :

```
LIBS+=-lopengl32 -lglu32
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use the old legacy OpenGL API you must add

```cpp
#include <GL/gl.h>
```

and link your app to your native platform opengl library (see QtCreator .pro files documentation to do this).

The new (better) way with QT 5 is to use QOpenGLFunctions. QOpenGLWidget provide cross-platform access to the OpenGL functions via

```
context()->functions()->glxxxx.
```

But not all the legacy functions are provided: only the common subset of OpenGL 1.x and ES 2.0. You have to rewrite your OpenGL code in a modern way (vertex buffer, shaders, ...).

You can also use higher OpenGL profiles with QOpenGLFunctions_X_X_profile include files like:

```cpp
#include <QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_core>
```

To use this higher version of OpenGL you also need to provide a compatible QSurfaceFormat to your QOpenGLWidget.

Answer (score 0):

To add to [LinWM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51941042/1688203), with CMake it would be like this:

```
# ...

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED Widgets)

# ...

target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
    general Qt5::Widgets ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY} ${OPENGL_glu_LIBRARY}
)
```

And then in sources:

```cpp
#include <GL/glu.h>
```

That helped me to resolve issues with `gluPerspective()` and `glFrustum()` functions on Windows 10.

Answer (score -3):

Did you include `GL/gl.h` properly?

Qt itself defines only a small subset of OpenGL functions for internal use, independently of system installed headers. I'm a bit surprised about `glClearDepth` but all the other functions and tokens have been removed from OpenGL-3 and later and Qt5 doesn't use them.